Apply ACL group automatically to "moved in" files?
If I want mygroup to have read/write access to all the descendant files/directories of /dir1, I could run setfacl -R -d -m g:mygroup:rwX /dir1.
The problem is that if I copy an existing directory like /dir2 inside of /dir1, dir2 does not get g:mygroup:rwX. I want all the current and future descendants of /dir1, whether they are newly-created, copied, or moved to have g:mygroup:rwX by default, automatically. That is, if I moved /dir2 into /dir1, /dir1/dir2/somefile.txt have g:mygroup:rwX.
Is this possible?
